# Android and JAX-RS

Tags: java, android, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a REST Client written on `Jersey`. It uses JAXB and JAX-RS. But when I try to add jar file with client to my Android application it crushes with error like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
```

Seams that `Android` actually doesn't support JAX-RS. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: It doesn't, at least in the sense that you expect. Googling for `android jaxrs` gives you several options on how to work with REST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android library like volley to make http requests to the jax-rs based api.

There is no need for a Jax-rs client and the need for android to support JAX-RS in perticular. REST-ful api's are supposed to be platform independent. So there is no requirement for client or the consumer of this api to support any perticular api or framework like Jax-rs.

speaking further,

Android uses ART/Dalvik virtual machine rather than JVM, therefore in that case it might not be able to compile a java based library? unless that library is also made available separately for android platform.